# React native timeout with a function

Tags: time, react-native

I have been stuck trying to get Timeout to work in my react-native project, I used SO and found lots of answers explaining that you must make it return a function so it must look like so

```
            setTimeout(function(){this.countLosses(counter, losses)},1000);
```

As apposed to

```
            setTimeout(this.countLosses(counter, losses),1000);
```

However when I run the former I get a undefined is not a function, and when i run the latter as expected the timeout does not work correctly.

The function I am trying to call looks like so

```
countLosses(counter:number, losses:array){
        if (counter<5) {
            this.clicked(losses.pop())
            counter=counter+1;
            setTimeout(function(){this.countLosses(counter, losses)},1000);
        }else{
            this.state = {
        animateTime: false,
        selected:[],

         }
        }
}
```

Comment: try this: `setTimeout(() => {this.countLosses(counter, losses)},1000);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay i finally figured it out

you must just add bind and then this in the brackets

so

```
setTimeout(this.countLosses.bind(this,counter, losses),1000);
```